# Apply Custom CSS for IPad devices

Tags: css, ipad

I have issue with showing my websites, in iPad devices. Some elements are not like CSS i specified.
For ex. i inserted this CSS for showing 3 images in one row.
But images show only 2 by row.

**Image where issue is showed**
[image]

I have this CSS inserted for images.

```
.sliki {
      width: 250px;
     length: 250px;
     display: inline-block;
     position:relative;
     float:left;
     padding:10px;
   }
```

but this CSS not apply for Ipads. On Other tablets are ok.

Also how to center form to be showed properly in iPads in this: 
[image]

This is also CSS that i have inserted for that part, but not persist on ipads.

this is page where all that elements are located.

Answer (score 0):

That `width` with that `padding` are the problem...
iPads screen have a width of 768px... So 3 images in a row, with a width of 250px plus the 20px of padding,  doesn't fit well.
You can use `@media queries`, and add a `max-width` and `width: 100%`....
Take a look [here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPad).

Comment: What about, centering the reviews part?